# Macro for Displaying / Hiding Rich Text Based on Dropdown Selection

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I'm attempting to create a Word document where a user can select a State in the dropdown and be presented with a link specific to that state.

To achieve this, I have a `DropDown List Content Control` with two options: Texas, and Oklahoma.

I have two blocks of text. One is bookmarked TexasText, the other is bookmarked Oklahoma text. The goal is for the user to select a state from the dropdown, and only see the specified text-block.

I'm using the following code in ThisDocument as an event handler:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl)
    If ContentControl.Title = "StateDropdown" Then
        Dim selectedValue As String
        Dim texasText As Range, oklahomaText As Range

        ' Get the selected value from the dropdown form field
        selectedValue = ContentControl.DropdownListEntries(ContentControl.DropdownListEntries(1).Index).Text

        ' Get the bookmark ranges
        Set texasText = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TexasText").Range
        Set oklahomaText = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("OklahomaText").Range

        ' Check if "Show All" is selected
        If selectedValue = "Show All" Then
            ' Show both Texas and Oklahoma text
            texasText.Font.Hidden = False
            oklahomaText.Font.Hidden = False
        ElseIf selectedValue = "Texas" Then
            ' Show Texas and hide Oklahoma text
            texasText.Font.Hidden = False
            oklahomaText.Font.Hidden = True
        ElseIf selectedValue = "Oklahoma" Then
            ' Show Oklahoma and hide Texas text
            texasText.Font.Hidden = True
            oklahomaText.Font.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And this is in the Module:

```
Sub UpdateTextVisibility()
    Dim selectedValue As String
    Dim texasText As Range, oklahomaText As Range
    
    ' Get the selected value from the dropdown form field
    selectedValue = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("StateDropdown")(1).DropdownListEntries(ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("StateDropdown")(1).DropdownListEntries(1).Index).Text
    
    ' Get the bookmark ranges
    Set texasText = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TexasText").Range
    Set oklahomaText = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("OklahomaText").Range
    
    ' Hide or show text based on the selected value
    If selectedValue = "Texas" Then
        texasText.Font.Hidden = False
        oklahomaText.Font.Hidden = True
    ElseIf selectedValue = "Oklahoma" Then
        texasText.Font.Hidden = True
        oklahomaText.Font.Hidden = False
    ElseIf selectedValue = "Show All" Then
        texasText.Font.Hidden = False
        oklahomaText.Font.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

My expectation is that when I update the dropdown selection, the content hides / shows accordingly. This is not occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the OnEnter event, which only fires when you *enter* the content control, not when you change the values.

If you use the OnExit event, the macro would run when you tab out of the content control. Unfortunately, Microsoft has never written an OnChange event, which is probably how you expect the dropdown to work.

Here is Greg Maxey's page about this shortcoming: [Content Controls](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html) And here is his page with programming to create a custom OnChange event: [Content Control Custom Events](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_custom_events.html)

Comment: The syntax shown in the question is what is generated when selecting the event from the dropdown, so it is correct, at least for Windows. I don’t have a Mac to compare it to.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt It's the same on Mac. The dropdown looks a little different when you make.a selection - instead of seeing the values listed in/below the listbox, Word pops up a little list at the bottom right of the control -  but otherwise AFAIK the behaviour is the same.

Comment: I've corrected my answer. But you'll still need to use Document_ContentControlOnExit or a custom event to get the text to update.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you probably need the Exit event, which has a slightly different signature:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
```

You also need to ensure you actually Exit the control (e.g. click outside it) or the event will not fire.

Second, for a DropDown List control it's simpler to get the visible Display Text of the control like this

```
selectedValue = ContentControl.Range.Text
```

You might hope that such a list would have a property saying which item in the list (1,2,3) had been selected, but it doesn't. So if you actually want the Value rather than the Displaytext, you have to iterate through the list, e.g. like this:

```
selectedValue = ""
With ContentControl
  For i = 1 To .DropdownListEntries.Count
    If .DropdownListEntries(i).Text = .Range.Text Then
      selectedValue = .DropdownListEntries(i).Value
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
End With
```

If you need the UpdateTextVisibility routine you would need to do a similar iteration in there.